# How to close a Window based on Table content of a table, by using a User Script?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, userscripts

I want to check for the cell located on the first row (not including header) and second column of a table. If the content is empty or '' I want the tab to get closed.

I have tried to assign the content to a variable, and if the value is equal to empty, to close the window, but is not working. In my table ('td')[0] is never empty, so that is why I need to check the second column of that row.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

Cell 2 should be empty for the window to close. Cell 1 is never empty on the table I am checking.

```
`function closeOpenedWindow() {
  window.close();
}

const innerTextOutput = $("#productdata td:nth-child(2)").innerText

function check(){
  'use strict';
  if(innerTextOutput == ''){
  closeOpenedWindow()
  }
}`
```

Thanks for any help!